# wrapper.find not working because of connect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

The following test case written with jest and enzyme is not working:

```
it('Displays Trade component', () => {
    console.log("Testing Shallow", wrapper)
    expect(wrapper.find('Trade').length).toEqual(1); 
  });
```

I used `console.log(wrapper.debug())` to console it and found the following:

`<Connect(Trade) tradeData={[undefined]} />`

How to identify the component now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to import your component outside of connect

do this:

```
export const Trade = () => {
   // your component Logic
}

<Connect(Trade) tradeData={[undefined]} />

then in your test file
```

import { Trade } from './trade'

```
you need to import it as a component itself OUTSIDE of Redux land
```

Comment: Yes, I had changed the structure for the same. What I did is I removed the connect from the component and placed it in the container... Now I am able to test.

Is there any way of doing the same you are telling without removing redux from it?